# Ubuntu Phone (14.10) Terminal Scroll up

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch

i own a Smartphone with Ubuntu Touch 14.10 on it.

I got an Error when installing something and the Error Message is that long that i can't see the first lines of it.

Is there a possibility in the Terminal to scroll up?

Edit-window looks like that:
[image]

UPDATE:

Thanks for your Answers, i piped the output to less, in this window i may scroll. This is a way to go, but I would be happy for more Answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scroll in the terminal app by using two fingers

Comment: when using 2 Fingers, it writes a=7 to the shell-input

Comment: afaik, 1 finger scrolls through your history and 2 finger scroll like a "normal window". At least this works on my Aquaris E5

Comment: Aquaris E5 to, does'nt work for me sry

Comment: What else did you change?  For me 2-finger scrolling just works too!

Comment: Updatet Ubuntu to 15.10 and now that works, thanks